# Is this a bug for IE8 using Jquery append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to solve this for days with no luck, This works fine on Firefox and Chrome, but not IE8
The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.get('./data.xml', function(data) {
        $($(data).children().find('attributes')[0]).append($('<item key="is">true</item>'));
        xml = data.xml ? data.xml : new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data);
        alert(xml);
    });
});
</script>
```

The data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
<user id="123" name="xxx">
    <attributes>
        <item key="test">123qwe</item>
    </attributes>
</user>
</result>
```

The result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
<user id="123" name="xxx">
    <attributes>
        <item key="test">123qwe</item>
        <item key="is">true</item>
    </attributes>
</user>
</result>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you may find this post useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923929/jquery-xml-parsing-manipulation-ie8-error

Comment: I got error Type mismatch on line 6497 using jquery 1.7.2

Comment: Here is line 6497:   fragment.appendChild( script );

Comment: @Senthil Kumar, I checked it out, but still not worked

Comment: Sorry! I am trying again, it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = $($.parseXML("<item key="is">true</item>")
              .getElementsByTagName('*')[0]);
$($(data).children().find('attributes')[0]).append(item);
```